# Database schema of comments

Tags: 7, comments

I would like to clarify the database table relationship between `comment` & `field_data_comment_body`.

Questions are:

1. Is `comment`'s body saved in `field_data_comment_body` table?
2. Is `comment`'s cid = `comment_body`'s entity_id ?
3. Is there any table other than these 2 contributed to comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Combined with 'entity_type' = 'comment', yes. An entity (comment, node, term, user, ..) is always identified by their entity_type and entity_id.
3. Not directly, in this case. There is also field_revision_comment_body table, which is in this case not used because comments don't support revisions (but field always needs to create one because nothing stops you from adding that field to a node and create revisions of it). There are also the field_config and field_instance_config tables which contain information about which field is attached to which entity type/bundle.